# Is there UI package in react.js for agora.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, agora.io

I was integrating agora.io into my react.js application. Right now agora is just providing video streams into a video HTML element. There are not any buttons, and this UI is looking horrible.

Do you know any UI kit or package which comes with prebuilt UI components, it can provide a zoom-like interface out of the box. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Agora's React UI Kit is in their pipeline. They have a lot of sample applications you can start building upon till then:

- https://github.com/akshatvg/Agora-RTM-Call-Invitation
- https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/AgoraWebSDK-NG/tree/master/ReactDemo
- https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/OpenAgoraWeb-React
- https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-rtc-react